# Detectar por javascript que mi navegador se muestra en movil

Tags: javascript

Buenas, una función o método en javascript que detecte que mi web se muestre en web o en dispositivo móvil.

Comment: [Mira esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

Comment: @Borch, eres usuario de varios mese porque no mejorar la pregunta, agrega lo que has tratado, un poco más de investigación,  revisa nuevamente [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira este codigo es el que yo siempre utilizo para poder pobrarlo debes abrir la consola y darle a la opcion "toggle device toolbar" para que te lo reconosca como mobile de lo contrario de retornara null.

```js
var mobile = {
  Android: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
  },
  BlackBerry: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
  },
  iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
  },
  Opera: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
  },
  Windows: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
  },
  any: function() {
    return (mobile.Android() || mobile.BlackBerry() || mobile.iOS() || mobile.Opera() || mobile.Windows());
  }
};


console.log(mobile.any())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Mobile</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <script src='app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¡Esto era! Gracias

Comment: genial!! me alegro que te haya servido

Answer (score 0):

Mira este post amigo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Dice que podrias usar Para poder Verificar que sea un dispositivo mobile segun su sistema operativo:
**Usando Regex**

```
    window.mobileAndTabletcheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Depende de a qué te refieras con "dispositivo móvil". Si lo que quieres es detectar dispositivos con resoluciones bajas puedes utilizar el método `matchMedia` para detectar si el dispositivo tiene una resolución menor que una que tú especifiques:

```js
for (var res=2500; res>0; res-=200){
  console.log('Resolución menor de ' + res + ' px: ' +
    window.matchMedia('(max-width: ' + res + 'px)').matches);
}
```

Otra técnica es la de comprobar el nombre del navegador o agente utilizado para ver si corresponde con alguno de los que se utiliza en dispositivos móviles pero esto implica tener que mantener en tu código una lista completa y actualizada lo cual puede resultar muy complicado.